# Image not resizing within the div when it rotates

Tags: jquery, html, css

here I am trying to rotate one image through jquery, but the problem what i am facing is, when i rotate left or right some part of the image is going out of the frame.. it is not resizing based on the css property; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; and it has a fixed width and auto height for this frame.

```
$(function(){
$("#right").click(function(){
    $("#image").rotate({ animateTo:90 });
});

$("#left").click(function(){
    $("#image").rotate({ animateTo:-90 });
});
$("#reset").click(function(){
    $("#image").rotate({ animateTo:0 });
}); });

<button id="right">Right</button><button id="left">Left</button><button id="reset">Reset</button><div class="previewimg"><img src="http://twistedsifter.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/shipwreck-beach-zakynthos-vertical-panorama-greece.jpg" id="image"></div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGrPQ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $("#right").click(function () {
        $("#image").rotate({
            animateTo: 90
        });
        $("#image").css("height", '268px');
    });
    $("#left").click(function () {
        $("#image").rotate({
            animateTo: -90
        });
        $("#image").css("height", '268px');
    });
    $("#reset").click(function () {
        $("#image").rotate({
            animateTo: 0
        });
        $("#image").css("height", '100%');
    });
});
```